SCRAM authentication method in Psycopg2 and Python 2.7
I have an old application based on python 2.7 which is currently using psycopg2 2.7.4 and using latest releases of postgresql I got the error "pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above." which is listed also in other stackoverflow questions.
I read that this issue is fixed on psycopg2 >=2.9.3 but it looks like this version only works on python3; unfortunately I cannot upgrade the application. I know that I can change the settings of postgresql by restoring old authentication method but I am looking a way (if any) to solve the issue without upgrading python.
Is it possible ?
thanks

You might try building psycopg2 from source against a newer version of libpq. FYI, psycopg2 2.8.6 is the last version that supports Python 2.7.
